# C++ Multiple inheritance, virtual method override problems, and covariant return type

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am inheriting two classes,[TFoamIntegrand](http://root.cern.ch/root/html/src/TFoamIntegrand.h.html), and IBaseFunctionMultiDim, which are both abstract classes. The problem I have is that I want to be able to use the Clone Member function which for IBaseFunctionMultiDim is a pure virtual with no arguments, and for TFoamIntegrand it is not a pure virtual in TFoamIntegrand but has an argument (with a default value).

```
class TObject {
   public:
      virtual TObject    *Clone(const char *newname="") const;
   ...
};

class TFoamIntegrand : public TObject  {
public:
   virtual Double_t Density(Int_t ndim, Double_t *) = 0;
   ...
};

class IBaseFunctionMultiDim {
   public:
      /** 
        Clone a function. 
        Each derived class must implement his version of the Clone method
      */
      virtual IBaseFunctionMultiDim * Clone() const = 0;  
    ...
}
```

The only way I can make it compile is to do:

```
class InSANEDiffXSec : public TFoamIntegrand, public ROOT::Math::IBaseFunctionMultiDim {
   public:
      virtual ROOT::Math::IBaseFunctionMultiDim*  Clone() const ;
   ...
}
```

Of course this produces the warnings about hiding the Clone with the argument. I have tried the following but I get covariant return type errors.

```
  virtual ROOT::Math::IBaseFunctionMultiDim*  Clone(const char * newname = "") const ;
  virtual InSANEDiffXSec*  Clone(const char * newname = "") const ;
```

I thought that the last version above was the correct one, according to my understanding of covariant return types. What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is a complete example:

```
class A {
  public:
     virtual A* Clone(const char * name="") { return( new A());}
};

class B {
  public:
     virtual B* Clone() = 0;
};

class C : public A {
  public:
     virtual double Density(int ndim, double *) = 0;
};

class D : public C, public B {
   public:
      virtual double Density(int ndim, double *x) {
         return 0.0;
      }
      //virtual D* Clone(const char * name="") { return( new D());}
      virtual B* Clone() { return( new D());}
};
```

It compiles. Changing to the commented line gives:

```
test.h: In member function ‘virtual D* D::Clone(const char*)’:
test.h:24:62: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘D’
       virtual D* Clone(const char * name="") { return( new D());}
                                                              ^
test.h:19:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘D’:
 class D : public C, public B {
       ^
test.h:11:17: note:     virtual B* B::Clone()
      virtual B* Clone() = 0;
                 ^
test.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cxx:7:18: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘D’
    D * d = new D();
                  ^
In file included from test.cxx:2:0:
test.h:19:7: note:   since type ‘D’ has pure virtual functions
 class D : public C, public B {
```

Comment: Please read http://sscce.org and apply it to your question.  Get rid of the cruft!

Comment: I had lots of links to code the well documented code but I could only post one link because of my lack of reputation on this site.

Comment: I am asking for *less code* not more.  Please read http://sscce.org

Comment: Your example is there. Please tell me what is wrong with it.

Comment: Your edited version compiles fine for me, even with the commented line in: http://ideone.com/74Lnzm

Comment: adding int main() { D d; d.Clone(); } results in: error: call of overloaded ‘Clone()’ is ambiguous

Comment: Much better!  But, what need do you have for the `Density` method(s)?  If you remove it, the error remains.  And what need do you have for `class C`?  If you remove it (and replace it with `A` in `D`), the same error remains.

Comment: @Chowlett OP switched which line was commented out, instead of leaving both in.

Comment: BTW default argument in virtual method should be avoided.

Comment: @Chowlett exactly what I did. I did not know that you need both because even with default arguments, it does not override the 0 argument version.@Jarod42 cannot avoid in this case.

Comment: whit2333 - You should always avoid bad design, and this is a bad design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compiles:

```
class TObject {
   public:
      virtual TObject    *Clone(const char *newname="") const = 0;
};

class IBaseFunctionMultiDim {
   public:
      virtual IBaseFunctionMultiDim * Clone() const = 0;  
};

class InSANEDiffXSec :
  public TObject,
  public IBaseFunctionMultiDim
{
   public:
      virtual InSANEDiffXSec*  Clone(const char* newname) const
      {
         return nullptr;
      }
      virtual InSANEDiffXSec*  Clone() const
      {
         return Clone(nullptr);
      }
};
```

but I did remove stuff from your code that did not seem to be relevant.

Comment: So what is happening here? Doesn't the default argument take care of the the second Clone?

Comment: @whit2333 default arguments are things that happen at the *call site*.  A function `foo(int x = 7)` is a function `foo(int x)` with instructions "when calling, if the caller does not give you an `x`, use `7`".  The function still takes 1 parameter that is an `int`.  So your `const char* newname=""` overload is an overload of the `const char*` version of the function, and does not overload the 0 argument version of the function.

Comment: Thanks. Does the same thing go for the constructor? If I only have a constructor with a default argument, does it still use it as the default constructor?

Comment: The call site will invoke `()`, which will find the constructor with the default argument and use it.  The implicit 0 argument constructor will also be removed (there are lots of things that can cause the 0 argument constructor to be removed in C++, same with copy constructor and copy assignment)

Comment: Ok the example compiled, but my new code still doesn't work. EDIT Nevermind. I missed something